# Iterating clip in ModelBuilder based on different province/county names using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: modelbuilder, clip, arcgis-pro, iterator

I have a featureclass with all counties/provinces from the Netherlands and I would like to do clips for roughly 8/9 counties based on their names in the feature class.

I have a feeling that I have to use one of the iterators for that, but I am not that really familiar with the iterators, so I was wondering which iterator I should use. I tried to use the **"Iterate Feature Selection"** and then afterwards the clip, however that didn't work. I filled for the null value the name of the counties/provinces, however I didn't get the clipped cities.

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.3

(I know it's fairly easy to do manually (since, it's only 8/9 counties(, however I would like to get more proficient with the ModelBuilder)

Comment: What does your model so far look like?

Comment: @PolyGeo to be honest, I don't have much in my model builder, initially I had the feature class with all the counties connected to the "Iterate Feature Selection" iterator and the output from this iterator connected to a clip function, however that didn't work. So in the end I deleted everything in my model builder.